# how to read/modify tags from a select2 box

Tags: jquery-select2

I am facing a simple problem. I have a **select2** box and I want to read/change the tags.
How can I do this? There seems to be no way to select the current tags with jquery.

My **select2** box looks like this:

```
$('#element').select2({
  tags: tagList,
  showSearchBox: false,
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
  width: "336px",
  maximumSelectionSize: 10
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you want to modify tags in generated code of select2?

Comment: yes, i have a few **select2** boxes which all use the same **tagList**. Whenever a user select a tag i want it to be removed from the other select2 boxes taglists.

Comment: So just remove it from real select list and update select2. That's all.

Comment: thats what I try but how do i update the tag attribute in select2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to update original list of `select`:

1) You have list:

```
<select class='myList'>
  <option value='a'>A</option>
  <option value='b'>B</option>
  <option value='c'>C</option>
</select>
```

2) You init select2 for lists:

```
$('.myList').select2();
```

3) User selects option of `B`, so you remove it from other lists:

```
// take all 'select' elements that is not current one.
//'this' shows to <select> tag. Try looking for some values from select2, to better access real element.
$('.myList').not(this).find('option[value="' + $('option:selected', this).val() + '"]').remove();
```

4) And you update select2 for all lists:

```
$('.myList').select2();
```

Comment: @user3244369 Accept answer than